# How to apply a custom function with a window parameter in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to following pandas dataframe:

```
a

1.0
1.5
1.3
1.2
1.9
0.8
```

Then I want to apply my new custom function to this column, which has a `window` parameter, I mean, it only has to treat n items from the starting point:

```
def hislack(x, window):
   # I only want to work with the last n items
   x = x[:-window,]
   # and do some stuff (this is a nosense example, just a simple sum)
   r = np.sum(x)
   return r
```

So to apply this function into a new column called `b` I used this:

```
df['b'] = hislack(df['a'].values, 3)
```

But it returns the following:

```
a     b

1.0   3.9
1.5   3.9
1.3   3.9
1.2   3.9
1.9   3.9
0.8   3.9
```

Which is the result of only the last row: `0.8 + 1.9 + 1.2 = 3.9`

So the expected output would be:

```
a     b

1.0   Nan
1.5   Nan
1.3   3.8
1.2   4.0
1.9   4.4
0.8   3.9
```

How may I prevent applying same result of the formula for all the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [DataFrame.rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df['a'].rolling(3).sum()       # here 3 is the window parameter for your function and sum
                               # is the function/operation you want to apply to each window
#0    NaN
#1    NaN
#2    3.8
#3    4.0
#4    4.4
#5    3.9
#Name: a, dtype: float64
```

---

Or:

```
df['a'].rolling(3).apply(sum)
```

More generally you can do: `df['a'].rolling(window).apply(fun)` where you pass the `window` parameter to `rolling` and the function to `apply`.